# SciPy Griddata "got multiple values for argument 'method' " error

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

**

I have a problem about griddata coordinates and it give a typeerror : griddata() got multiple values for argument 'method'

```
fig=plt.figure()

ax=fig.gca(projection='3d')

yi  =np.linspace(1,25)

xi  =np.linspace(1,25)

X,Y =np.meshgrid(xi,yi)

for i in range(1,6)

    z=df.iloc[:, i]

    y=sorted(range(1,len(z)+1)) 

    print("y=",y)

    print("len y=",len(y)) #->len y = 24

    a=np.array([i,i+1]*len(z)).reshape((24,2))

    print("a shape=", a.shape)

    print("a=",a)

    print("len a=",len(a))

    #->  len a = 24  

    b =list(itertools.chain(*zip(z,z)))

    b = np.array(b).reshape((24,2))

    print("b shape=", b.shape)
   #->  len b = 24

   Z = griddata(a,y,b,(xi,yi),method="nearest")
```

and it gives an error

> Z = griddata(a,y,b,(X,Y),method="nearest") 
>       TypeError: griddata() got multiple values for argument 'method'

X coordinates contain [1,2],[2,3] and y coordinates contain 1 to 24 and Z coordinates contain some values and they are 24 values each column
I could not solve interpolate error

Thank You**

Comment: Take another looks at the signature of the function in the [griddata docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html), and compare that to how you called it.

Comment: I have already compared that but I have [2,1] array points and [1,1] dimension array for X and Y axis. So I could not integrate griddata docstring example directly

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved that. scipy-interpolate griddata use [:,1] array also, so it could not accept my 2D arrays as point

Working code is here, Thank you

```
fig=plt.figure()

ax=fig.gca(projection='3d')

for i in range(1,6):
    z=df.iloc[:, i]

    y=np.array(sorted(list(range(1,len(z)+1))*2)).reshape((48,1)) 

    a=np.array([i,i+1.2]*len(z)).reshape((48,1))

    points = np.concatenate((a, y), axis=1)
    b =list(itertools.chain(*zip(z,z)))
    b = np.array(b).reshape((48,1))

    yi  =np.linspace(min(a),max(a))

    xi  =np.linspace(min(y),max(y))

    X,Y =np.meshgrid(yi,xi)

    Z = griddata(points,b,(yi,xi),method="linear")
```